# handling .d.ts files with Awesome Typescript Loader

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I've recently upgraded my Angular2 version to the Final one and have a problem with [awesome-typescript-loader](https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader/) that wants one declaration file. How can I do it and where to link that typings file?
I use the [angular2-webpack-starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter). I have a few .d.ts files in my app providers definitions.

For now all the tries to compile them end with something like:

```
Module build failed: Error: Debug Failure. False expression: Output generation failed
at Object.assert (node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:2407:23)
at Object.transpileModule (node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:54401:18)
at State.fastEmit (node_modules\awesome-typescript-loader\src\host.ts:264:39)
at transform (node_modules\awesome-typescript-loader\src\index.ts:164:28)
at transformationFunction (node_modules\awesome-typescript-loader\src\index.ts:89:48)
at compiler (node_modules\awesome-typescript-loader\src\index.ts:105:34)
at Object.loader (node_modules\awesome-typescript-loader\src\index.ts:18:18)
@ ./src/app/providers/socket/index.ts 6:9-40
@ ./src/app/providers/socket/chat-service.ts
@ ./src/app/pages/restricted/restricted.ts
@ ./src/app/app.routes.ts
@ ./src/app/app.module.ts
@ ./src/app/index.ts
@ ./src/main.browser.ts
@ multi main
```

The advice from ATL readme:

```
All declaration files should be resolvable from the entry file. The easiest way to do this is to create a references.d.ts file which contains references to all of your declaration files. Then reference references.d.ts from your entry file.
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I excluded .d.ts files from input sources and instead defined the location of .d.ts files using the typingsRoot property of tsconfig.json.   It does seem silly that an error should be thrown when an input file results in no output.  This would be fairly common such as a file containing only an interface definition.

Answer (score 0):

As my .d.ts files contained interfaces only, I've renamed them all to [something]`.interface.ts`. Now I've just `custom-typings.d.ts` that is linked in `tsconfig.json` for other things.